# JavaScript . разный результат обращения к свойству объекта через точку и квадратные скобки

Tags: javascript

В одном случаи всё правильно выводится, результаты свойств, когда пишу через квадратные скобки

```js
const options = {
    name:'test',
    width:1024,
    height:1024,

     colors : {
        border:'black',
        bg:'red'

    }
};

for (let key in options){
    console.log(options[key]);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если поставить точку

```
for (let key in options){
console.log(options.key);
```

}

, то в результате вывода переменная не определенна , почему так происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const options = {
    name:'test',
    width:1024,
    height:1024,

     colors : {
        border:'black',
        bg:'red'

    }
};

for (let key in options){
    console.log(options.key);
}
```

Comment: `options.key` это всё равно что `options['key']` — то есть ключ после точки воспринимается буквально как строковой ключ объекта.

Comment: из статьи: Квадратные скобки также позволяют обратиться к свойству, имя которого может быть результатом выражения. Например, имя свойства может храниться в переменной

Answer (score -1):

Дело в том , что во время перебора через `for in` ключ получает строку.
И когда вы пытаетесь получить данные через точку. JS это видит так `options.'name'` , а не так `options.name`.

```js
const options = {
    name:'test',
    width:1024,
    height:1024,

     colors : {
        border:'black',
        bg:'red'

    }
};

for (let key in options){
    console.log(typeof key);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, странно, почему интересно так происходит, ведь в объекте были и цифровые типы данных, почему он своевольно переменную конвертирует? Или переменная первый аргумент  в цикле for in всегда равна строковому типу данных?

Comment: *"JS это видит так `options.'name'`"* - нет, не так

Comment: Он каждый раз видит именно что `options.key`, а свойства `key` в объекте нет, потому возвращается undefined